# Remove the JTabbedPane "currently selected" dotted line

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

How do you remove the dotted line around the currently selected tab on a JTabbedPane.

For example:

[image]

See the dotted line around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found a better way:

```
component.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: good idea, that works because the dotted lines are for the selected *and* focussed tab (not just the selected one)

Answer (score 5):

try setting the focus colour

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.focus", new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

or set it to the same colour as the background

Answer (score 3):

- This is painted by the current Look
  and Feel.
- I believe what is needed
  will depend on the LnF you're using.
- You'll want to create a custom
  TabbedPaneUI class, probably
  overriding the one in your chosen
  L&F. You might be overriding `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI`.
- override `paintFocusIndicator`, and make it an empty method.
- You will need to create an instance of this class, then call `myTabbedPane.setUI(myTabbedPaneUI)`

Comment: this is very useful because UI delegates are a poorly discussed topic, but they are not necessarily difficult to use.